# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ~repository

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm getting a strange error with my nestjs code.
Repository not connected in module file

`[ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context`

The current code is this

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import connectionOptions from 'ormconfig';
import { UserModule } from './modules';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(connectionOptions), UserModule],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

user.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserRepository } from 'src/repositories';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository])],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

user.repository.ts

```
import { User } from '../entities';
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';

@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  async findOneById(userId: string) {
    return await this.createQueryBuilder()
      .where('user_id = :userId', {
        userId,
      })
      .getOne();
  }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

From the code you provided, there should be no problem. The only thing that will trigger the error is the `ormconfig` config you did not provide.

Can you check if you have `name: "xxxx"` in your `ormconfig` config like below:

```json
{
  name: 'dbname', <-- check if you have name config here
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  ...
}
```

There are 2 ways to solve it if you have name in the config:

1. If there is only **ONE database**, you can **remove the name** and use the default name typeorm provides.
2. If you have **multiple databases** or you want to preserve the connection name, you will need to specify the name in the code as well to help typeorm to determine which database to work with, see the below changes:

user.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository], 'dbname'), // provide the name here
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

user.service.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository, 'dbname') // provide the name here
    private usersRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}
  ...
}
```